# ngIf to set a color?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this json:

```
[{
    "nodename": "Main application Server",
    "enabled": true
},
 {
    "nodename": "Main Server",
    "enabled": false
}]
```

and i show this data in my template with ngFor:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let list of lists">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title text-center">Server: {{ list.nodename }}, {{ list.enabled }}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>   
         </div>
<div>
```

And now, i would set to different color on my `panel-primary` in template: if `"enabled": true`, than set a green color, and if `"enabled": false`, set a red color. How do this? with `ngIf=...`? Or something else?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could leverage the ngStyle directive:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary"
    [ngStyle]="{'background-color': list.enabled? 'green' : 'red'}">
```

or ngClass:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary"
    [ngClass]="{greenClass: list.enabled, redClass: !list.enabled}">
```

With the following styles in your component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  styles: [
    `
      .greenClass { background-color: green }
      .redClass { background-color: red }
    `
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a CSS class - and toggle the class via `ngClass`

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-class="{'green-class': list.enabled, 'red-class' : !list.enabled }">
```