# Change class dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a list which renders dynamically using a ngFor directive. The data comes from an SQL Lite DB. I am trying to append a class to each list item based on the data present. i.e if the list item is an "Expense" then append a red class, if the list item is an "Income" then append a green class. I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873480/ngif-to-set-a-color) but it only checks for true/false and not exact text.

My code is as follows

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let expense of expenses; let i=index">
  <ion-item nopadding [ngStyle]="{greenClass: expense.type==='Income', redClass: expense.type==='Expense'}">
    <p>
      <span>Day of month: {{expense.day}}</span><br>
      Type: {{expense.type}}<br>
      Description: {{expense.description}}
    </p>
    <h3 item-end>
      Amount: R{{expense.amount}}
    </h3>
  </ion-item>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Comment: You should use `[ngClass]` instead of `[ngStyle]`

Comment: oops thanks, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `ngStyle` instead of `ngClass`.

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let expense of expenses; let i=index">
  <ion-item nopadding [ngClass]="{greenClass: expense.type==='Income', redClass: expense.type==='Expense'}">
    ...
  </ion-item>
</ion-item-sliding>
```